# How to i use join?

Tags: oledb

I get a "syntax error in from clause" exception error. I write OleDB. What is the reason?

```
string selectCommand = @"SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID";
```

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of the inner, outer. left, right, etc join

```
string selectCommand = @"SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID";
```

Comment: Problem is solved, thanks @kooskoos

Comment: Glad, I was able to help. Would you accept the answer?

Comment: Allows you to reply within 7 minutes, quick reply, thanks @kooskoos

Comment: Happy Holidays:)